# Guice injection on nested classes of CLI App

Tags: guice, guice-3

I am writing a command line interface application that is connecting to an oracle database using MyBatis and injection done by Guice.

My question is with injection of nested classes.  My class structure looks pretty much like this

```
MyInjector
Main
--Menu1
----Service1
----MenuA
------Service2
--------MenuAB
----------Service1
--Menu2
```

Now I need my user to type their login and password into the app (can't have it in a config file) so Main initializes the MyInjector, grabs the injector object from that, and uses that to inject and initialize Menu1.  The problem is, once im in Menu1, it needs to go to MenuA and MenuA is going to need to inject services, and who knows how deep this will end up going.

Now, my first thought would be to make MyInjector a singleton class and just constantly get instances of it wherever needed and grab the injector field that was created by the Main class in the beginning, but im kinda curious as to if there's a better way.

Is there a more Guicey way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what You need is `@AssistedInject`? You pass arguments to factory method and get the instance of top level object with it. All other appropriately annotated fields are injected automatically.